# Extract days digit present in string in r

Tags: r, split

I want to extract days digits occurring in string into a list. Appreciate if anyone could suggest the easy way.

```
x<- 'At 02:04 AM, 09:04 AM, 03:04 PM and 08:04 PM, on day 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 of the month'
```

Expecting the result in a list like: `"21"  "22"  "23"  "24"  "25"  "26"  "27"  "28"  "29"  "30"  "31"  "1"   "2"   "3"   "4"   "5"   "6"   "7"   "8"   "9" "10"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try matching on the following pattern:

```
\b\d{1,2}\b(?!:\d{2})
```

A sample script:

```
x <- "At 02:04 AM, 09:04 AM, 03:04 PM and 08:04 PM, on day 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 of the month"
m <- gregexpr(" \\b\\d{1,2}\\b(?!:\\d{2})", x, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(x, m)[[1]]

[1] " 21" " 22" " 23" " 24" " 25" " 26" " 27" " 28" " 29" " 30" " 31" " 1" 
[13] " 2"  " 3"  " 4"  " 5"  " 6"  " 7"  " 8"  " 9"  " 10"
```

The regex pattern used says to match:

```
\b\d{1,2}\b    one or two digits, surrounded by word boundaries on both sides
(?!:\d{2})     then assert that what follows the last digit is NOT a :00 time
               component
```

Note that the negative lookahead `(?!:\d{2})` is very necessary here, because it lets us avoid accidentally matching the digits from the hour/minute timestamps.

Comment: Read about lookarounds in regex, because they are very powerful (and pretty much necessary here).  I comment when I feel that the answer would not be obvious to someone who has at least a basic knowledge of regex :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like that:

```
library(stringr)
days <- c(
# separated by commas
as.numeric(str_extract_all(str_extract_all(x, ' \\d+,'), '\\d+')[[1]]), 
# in the 'and {day_num} of' text
as.numeric(str_extract_all(str_extract_all(x, 'and \\d+ of'), '\\d+')[[1]])
)
```

Of course you can merge the two `regex`ps together, but I would still prefer this as this answer deliberately distinguishes the two different contexts in which you can find day numbers.